# Trigger onscroll function when specific element is in viewport - jsfiddle inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this parallax scrolling.

Using tweenmax library

Right now scrolling is calculed/triggered for the whole page, so by the time i reach parallax elemets that are inside **#wrap**, they already moved a lot, i need to trigger calculating scrolling only after i reach parent element of parallax elements.

I want to trigger onsroll function only when i reach #wrap or for each individual #scroll-parallax-1-5 element

HTML:

```
<div class="asd"></div>
<div id="wrap">
<div class="scroll-parallax-1 a"></div>
<div class="scroll-parallax-2 b"></div>
<div class="scroll-parallax-3 c"></div>
<div class="scroll-parallax-4 d"></div>
<div class="scroll-parallax-5 e"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.onscroll = function(){
  console.log(0.8*scrollY);
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-1", {y: 0.1*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-2", {y: 0.2*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-3", {y: 0.4*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-4", {y: 0.7*-scrollY });
  TweenMax.set(".scroll-parallax-5", {y: 1.2*-scrollY });
}
```

**[Full jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/L7bt8rfk/)**

As you can see, by the time i reach **#wrap**, elements are already in the grey **.asd** div

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into the [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), where you can trigger the animation when the elements appears into view?

Comment: It has a threshold that you can you to trigger your tween with an offset(just before the element has become visible)